# Banned/censored books go to the "pulp mill"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

Would it be accurate to say that an author's censored books were "sent straight from the press **to the pulp mill**", i.e. shredded by the government? I got this translation from a translation engine, but I couldn't back it up with references, nor did I find this process described in other words.

Comment: Send to the pulp mill means literally send the books to the pulp factory. You are probably looking for  a figurative sense.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [pulp mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_mill) which suggests they don't usually use waste paper or books as an input. I don't know if you want an answer about the paper manufacturing process, which is very off topic. Or do you want an idiom for destroying books?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for an idiom about an author's book being systematically destroyed by the government/ruling power.

Comment: 'Were systematically / invariably shredded' is probably acceptable even if the books were burned. 'Sent to the pulp mill' has certainly been used for books, at least to describe the disposal of books say 100 years ago ([SAO/NASA](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1929JRASC..23..397S)). But if you want to be precisionist about the mode of destruction, you will need to spell it out.

Comment: I think you mean metaphor, and I think the most common is "book burning".

Comment: It means books were sent to be destroyed. But anyone can do that —publishers, libraries... It is not specific to the government doing it.

Answer (score 0):

A shredder and a pulp mill are two separate things; if you mean that the books are being literally shredded, you would just say "to the shredder(s)."

If you mean that the papers are being destroyed by some (unspecified) means, you could just say something like:

> The books were sent to the government for immediate destruction.

Comment: Sorry but "sent *to the government* for immediate destruction"? Where is that usual?

Answer (score 0):

Normally "sent to the pulp mill" occurs for literally pulping.  For instance, when a book was about to be released and a book reviewer proved, from an advance copy, that it contained fraudulent claims, the publisher withdrew it and sent all the books to the pulp mill.

Since a government could ban or censor a book at any time in the publication process, even before it is printed, there is only a limited time when we could say it went from the printers to the pulp mill.  Before printing, or when it had to be withdrawn from the stores, we could not.